# Missing icons from system settings KDE 15.04

Tags: icons, kde, backport

i have a missing icons from the Kubuntu System Settings panel, installed from kubuntu-ppa/backports in ubuntu 15.04 with kubuntu-desktop

any ideas?

Comment: In my case they are missing just for one of two users, but I didn't have time to investigate it yet.

Comment: What icons are missing?

Comment: attach link to screenshot: http://goo.gl/aU1mRy

Comment: maybe incompatibility from ubuntu-desktop to kubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I not use ppa from kubuntu but I use UbuntuStudio 15.04 and have the same problem, I only can make appear one icon, installing this package(the package **systemsettings** must be installed):

kde-config-gtk-style

see this picture (**the other icons are missing**):

[image: icon kde-config-gtk-style add on systemsettings]

**Note:** You can open from terminal with:

systemsettings5

I do not find the way to make appear the other icons, I need to configure the search option in dolphin file manager that not working because I use dolphin under UbuntuStudio 15.04, and I use kdenlive that have fonts very small, see:

[image]

At the momento I found a solution for the fonts on dolphin that is install this package:

qt4-qtconf

see this picture:

[image]

This run from terminal with:

qtconfig-qt4

or from system config UbuntuStudio

[image]

Only I don't understant why not working on kdenlive, there must be some missing package to install that I don't know what is (on UbntuStudio 14.04 this problem there is no)